# How to make a horizontal recycler view but only two images appear at a time even user scrolls

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, carousel

I am building a movie app, where I would like to display a horizontal recycler view with movie images and their titles. I want to develop it in a way that 2 movie images will be displayed and when users scroll horizontally the images will change with a snap 1 by 1 or 2 by 2 without scrolling continuously.

[image]

[image]

In the adapter class, I get the width of the screen and I manually divide it by 2.26, so the 2 images/cardviews will be displayed.
In the fragment class I use the adapter and the snaphelper to make the recycler view scroll as snap.

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code what you did till now ?

Comment: Yes, I have provided some of my code.